# Subtracting every column in a row for similar row numbers in two separate files

Tags: awk

If I have two files:

file1

```
2,3,1,4,5,2,1
1,2,4,6,3,1,3
1,2,1,1,1,1,1
```

file2

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

I want to subtract all the numbers from the same row numbers of each file. So all the numbers of row 1 from file 1 minus all the numbers of row 1 of file 2 and so forth.

Output:

```
1,2,0,3,4,1,0
0,1,3,5,2,0,2
0,1,0,0,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ paste -d, file1 file2 | awk -F, '{n=NF/2; s=""; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {printf "%s%s", s, $i-$(i+n); s=",";}; print ""}'
1,2,0,3,4,1,0
0,1,3,5,2,0,2
0,1,0,0,0,0,0
```

#### How it works

- `paste -d, file1 file2`

  This combines the files, row by row.
- `n=NF/2; s=""; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {printf "%s%s", s, $i-$(i+n); s=",";}`

  This subtracts and prints.
- `print ""`

  This prints a newline character at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [two dimensional arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html) with GNU Awk:

```
$ cat subtract_fields.awk
BEGIN
{
    FS=OFS=","
}
{
    if(FNR==NR) {
        for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
            a[FNR][i]=$i
    } else {
        for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
            $i=a[FNR][i]-$i
        delete a[FNR]
        print
    }
}
$ awk -f subtract_fields.awk file1 file2
1,2,0,3,4,1,0
0,1,3,5,2,0,2
0,1,0,0,0,0,0
```